# Using fzf with tmux and zsh on Mac

Tags: zsh, tmux

I really like fzf when I use it, but it's difficult to actually use it. For example, I don't want to have to type `vim $(fzf)` every time I want to fuzzy find for a file. Ideally, I'd like to be able to just type `ctrl-E` to enter fzf and start editing the file after selecting it by pressing enter.

I don't know what keys are being pressed to accomplish what's done in the video on the github page (https://github.com/junegunn/fzf). Pressing tab just does normal auto-completion (and I don't want to do the `**` style autocompletion. I want to enter fzf-tmux and have it paste the result into my command)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [install](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/install) script of fzf will setup such key bindings for you, `CTRL-T`, `CTRL-R`, and `ALT-C`. Refer to the [the project home page](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) for the details. The code for the key bindings can be found [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.zsh).

If you do not like the default ones fzf provides, you can try writing your own.

```
# A simple widget for dictionary words
fzf-dict-widget() {
  LBUFFER="$LBUFFER$(cat /usr/share/dict/words | fzf-tmux -m | paste -sd" " -) "
  zle reset-prompt
}
bindkey '^E' fzf-dict-widget
zle     -N   fzf-dict-widget
```

Comment: Are you saying that the video on the home page uses a custom script that doesn't come with the installer?

Comment: Oh... I see. I guess I misread that, and it doesn't work exactly when I try it, but it's probably just a small environment problem. Thank you!